# Using react-i18next, how can share the TFunction between common functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, i18next

I'm using react-i18next and am trying to find a way to share a TFunction within shared functions. For example, let's say I have a react component where I create the TFunction using the useTranslation hook and initiate two resources.

```
const { t } = useTranslation(["ns1", "ns2"]);
```

I also have a function that I want to be used by various components and pages and which uses translation from the "ns2" resource e.g.

```
const sharedFunction = (t: TFunction<["ns2"]>) => {
    return t("someString");
}
```

How can I pass my initial instance of t into my shared function, currently if I try I get a typescript error ("ns1" is not assignable to "ns2"), which makes perfect sense given the typings. Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: In my ide I can see `t` is typed as `TFunction<[string, string], undefined>` if I define it like yours, maybe that works

Comment: Thanks. I think this depends upon how i18next is configured. If it is configured to support strong typing e.g. https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript then the resource names are strongly typed constants, rather than just strings. e,g 

TFunction<["ns1", "ns2"], undefined>

instead of 

TFunction<[string, string], undefined>